# URLrequest cache response not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I want to cache the response of a urlRequest for offline usage in Adobe Air.  When I compile for flash player the cache works and I get the response even when I disconnect the network, but when I compile for Adobe Air I get error. PS:  useCache and cacheResponse dose not work!

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , callReq)
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()

    function callReq(e:Event):void 
    {
            //URLRequestDefaults.manageCookies = true; 
        //URLRequestDefaults.useCache = true;
        var r:String = "http://onecom.no/presentation_json.php?what=get_slides&slide_id[]=2540"
        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(r)

        //  urlRequest.cacheResponse = true
        //  urlRequest.useCache = true

            urlRequest.url = r
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , Comp)
        loader.load(request)
    }

    function Comp(e:Event):void 
    {
        trace( e.target.data)   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Air can not use the browsers cache. I had to build my own cache class that saves all URLRequest responses to a Shared Object and loads them if there is no internet connection

Answer (score 0):

save them to variables and store them in the local SQLlite database on your device/computer?...
[Using local SQLlite on device](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/encrypted_database_flash.html)